# Magento2 adding radio buttons in customoptions

Tags: magento2

Can anyone Help me to add radio button to custom options for product at product level for input type drop_down magento2 admin

Help me great

Answer (score 2):

You can add **custom option as radio button** from magento 2 backend .

**Follow the below steps :**

1. Logged in to magento 2 admin panel -> click on products ->catalog
2. It will display all the products -> add/edit any products
3. So on the product form you will see customizable options
4. Click on customizable options -> Select option type as Radio button
5. Add your options and its value and click on Save
6. Check on frontend side it will display custom options with radio button .

**For more reference refer below screenshot :**

**Backend**

[image]

**Frontend**

[image]

Comment: Sorry It is not proper answers for above given question Manthan Dave,it is in drop_down option for showing default creating radio button at product level

Answer (score 0):

If You want add to product level custom option look in these file path to add

your code

**File Path :  vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php**

**step-1:Defing the variable**

```
const FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME = 'default_radio';
```

Step-2: in Function getCommonContainerConfig() You have to declare method to

use const variable

```
children' => [

    static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME => $this->getIsDefaultFieldConfig(150)

]
```

Step - 3:To which Grid type You want to Assign the Custom option

```
protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder)
    {

return [

'children' => [

static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME => $this-> getIsDefaultFieldConfig(200)

]

];
```

Step 4:To which Datatype You want to Assign the Custom option Should Define

Here

```
 protected function getTypeFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {

'indexes' => [

 static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME

]
```

Step 5: code to call getIsDefaultFieldConfig(150) Which defined in step-2

```
protected function getIsDefaultFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Default'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Radio::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'value' => '0',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Before These All You need to define in xml for radio go for below Path

File Path:

**vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml**

Add below Code after checkbox

```
<!--these is added for defining the radio button -->
     <radio class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Radio">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/radio</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </radio>
```

Step 6:You have create a column under your Database

catalog_product_option_type_value create a column that is defined in step 1.

You can See the radio box

Comment: This solution is offering changing core code which is highly not recommended.

Comment: Its not working ???