# How to add radio button in custom option in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, php-7, ui-form, ui

I want to add radio button in custom option .

I refer this link [Magento2 adding radio buttons in customoptions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165337/magento2-adding-radio-buttons-in-customoptions).

But not working.

If anything i want to chage it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this answer "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165337/magento2-adding-radio-buttons-in-customoptions#answer-165340"

Comment: I refered same link but product view page not loaded?

Comment: did you checked exception log when product page was not loaded ?