# How to add radio button in ui modifier

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to add radio button using ui modifier

```
return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Default'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Radio::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'value' => '0',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

But not working

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add full code ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/how-to-add-radio-button-in-custom-option-in-magento2